# How to find out about standard apps in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-browser

how can I fire the default app for file browsing on Android >= API level 7? There is no app like this that comes with Android, so is there an Intent like `android.intent.action.fileexplore`? How can I find out whether an application is installed that can display the contents of a folder? And how can I "talk" to it?

Thanks a lot!

Be well
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I fire the default app for file browsing on Android >= API level 7?

There is no such concept in Android.

> There is no app like this that comes with Android, so is there an Intent like android.intent.action.fileexplore?

No.

> How can I find out whether an application is installed that can display the contents of a folder?

You can try an `ACTION_PICK` `Intent` with a `Uri` pointing to the folder in question, but my guess is that 99.9% of Android devices will not have anything to respond to this `Intent`.